# Typescript + select2 + browserify = TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, jquery-select2, browserify

i decided to migrate a one of my projects frontend to typescript + browserify (to learn this stuff), everything went well until i come across "TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"... After many wasted hours of googling and testing differend approaches,imports etc. without any result... well it is time to hit stackoverflow.com :)

My setup is:

(you can clone all this as testing project from here https://github.com/Salamek/ts-select2)

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./ts/**/*"
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "select2": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/select2": "^4.0.47",
    "browserify": "^16.2.2",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "errorify": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "tsify": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="select2">
      <option>Foo</option>
    </select>
  <script src="js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const watchify = require('watchify');
const errorify = require('errorify');
const del = require('del');
const tsify = require('tsify');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
//const runSequence = require('run-sequence');

function createBrowserifier(entry) {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: [entry],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
    .plugin(tsify)
    .plugin(watchify)
    .plugin(errorify);
}

function bundle(browserifier, bundleName, destination) {
    return browserifier
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(bundleName))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
}

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return del('./js/**/*')
});

gulp.task('tsc-browserify-src', () => {
    return bundle(
        createBrowserifier('./ts/main.ts'),
        'bundle.js',
        'js');
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    console.log('Watching...')
    gulp.watch(['ts/**/*.ts'], gulp.series('clean', 'tsc-browserify-src', 'watch'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', 'tsc-browserify-src', 'watch'));
```

ts/main.ts

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
declare var global: any;
global.jQuery = $;
global.$ = $;

import "select2";

$(function () {
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

After successful gulp tsc-browserify-src task without any error i get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.ts:10)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3534)
    at process (jquery.js:3602)
```

when opening index.html in browser.

Anyone know what to do ? What i'm doing wrong ? (till yesterday i was using plain jQuery, so pls slowly on me :-) )

*PS: My plan is to switch fully to angular.js for frontend stuff and abandon jQuery completely, but right now i need to get my app working with original components and rewrite app code to typescript, slowly dropping jQuery stuff...*